# Excel Textbox Sizing Handles Disappear & Cell References Don't Work After Worksheet Copy in .XLSM File

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For some reason, when I right-click on an Excel tab at the bottom, and select **Move or Copy...**, check the box for **Create a copy**, and then hit **Ok**. The textbox sizing handles are removed and cell references no longer work either on the newly copied sheet.

I even tried creating new text boxes on the copied sheet, but the sizing handles are not visible on any new textboxes that I create either.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a solution for it?

**Textbox with handles on original worksheet**

[image]

**Textbox with no handles on copied worksheet**

Also, cell references no longer work.

[image]

I'm working in **Microsoft Excel desktop app** with AutoSave On. Also, **it is a .XLSM file.**

Comment: You're on excel 2016 Desktop? Can you show the formula for the copied textboxes in your question? Is the textbox grouped with other textboxes? Are the references on another sheet than the one being copied? I am unable to replicate any of the issues you're reporting (the only one close is the sizing handles when the textbox is in a group, in which case clicking the box again makes it reappear).